# How packets are forwarded between interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, network-adapter

I have problems with understanding this topic.

I understand `iptables` packet flow as well as well as `kernel hooks`.

Do not take into account `iptables` rules, just `net.ipv4.ip_forward` enabled and iptables empty.

Consider host with two NICs. First is in `192.168.0.0/24` network, second - `10.10.0.0/24`. 
Packet comes to the first NIC with IP `10.10.0.3`.

My question is how kernel determines where to route packet ? 
Does it just check routing table and thats all ? If it finds routing entry that corresponds to this address than it takes NIC name and forwards this packet to the specific NIC ? Which is stored in `/proc/net/route` but really in the kernel RAM ? 
But if there is no such route it checks NIC(interfaces) that maybe one of them has specific IP even with network route entry in the table ?

Am I right ?